# Knife bootstrap failing through Jenkins execute shell

Tags: jenkins, aws-opsworks, knife

I'm trying to perform  a "knife bootstrap" command through Jenkins web UI execute shell, but I keep getting this error message :
(this is the knife bootstrap command I'm using) :

"**knife bootstrap [the node's IP] --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo --identity-file "[my key to the node]" --node-name My123 --run-list 'role[role1]'** "

and this is the error message:

" **ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/validation.pem** "

when I run the 'knife bootstrap' command directly through the CLI it works fine.

any idea why it's not working from Jenkins execute shell?

Comment: When you are calling `knife bootstrap`, is it from the same user as jenkins is running? Bootstrap process need to have proper chef configuration, you may need to point knife to proper client.rb.

Comment: Yes, and I also tried the export 
"export KNIFE_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins/starter_kit/.chef/ " command and the 
symlink command : "ln -s /var/lib/jenkins/starter_kit/.chef/ /var/lib/jenkins/"
, but still getting this error message.

Comment: Have you tried to add `--config`?

Comment: yes thanks, I have fixed it, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to validation.pem file is missing, this is default path for validation file. Either you can set path in /chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb file or you can use default location /etc/chef/validation.pem.

You can regenerate validation key from webUI and replace the existing one, this should resolve your issue.